# BCP into SQL Server with Tab Delimited

Tags: csv, sql-server-2008, bcp

I am trying to import a csv file with tab delimited and I enter this bcp command it asks me to enter the column data type for every column. Any way I can edit this so I don't need to do this? Thanks!

```
bcp DW.dbo.ACSFlight \\gsc\Lib\Drop\Database\DataLoad\BCP_Files\ACSFlight_july2nd\ACSFlight705.dat -S JBBWIMDBS37 -T
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is. Create a format file first using the [`bcp -format nul`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility?view=sql-server-2017#format) option. Once you have this format file, specify this format file in your import command using the [`-f format_file`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility?view=sql-server-2017#f) option.